How to integrate LDAP with .NET 8 based Blazor Web App (Server-Side)?
I am trying to integrate authentication with our LDAP server for .NET 8 Blazor Web App.
My launchSettings.json
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
    "iisSettings": {
      "windowsAuthentication": false,
      "anonymousAuthentication": true,
      "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:25412",
        "sslPort": 44310,
        "environmentVariables": {
          "UserDomains": "mycorp=LDAP://mycorp.com"
        }
      }
    },
    "profiles": {
      "http": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5102",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
          "UserDomains": "mycorp=LDAP://mycorp.com"
        }
      },
      "https": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7038;http://localhost:5102",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
          "UserDomains": "mycorp=LDAP://mycorp.com"
        }
      },
      "IIS Express": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
          "UserDomains": "mycorp=LDAP://mycorp.com"
        }
      }
    }
  }

UserLogin.razor
@page "/userlogin"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using System.Text
@using System.DirectoryServices
@using RCBuisinessLogic
@using RCBuisinessLogic.Authentication
@using RCWebApp.Models
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject UserInformation UserInformation

<div class="user-login" style="height: 630px;">
    <EditForm Model="@Login" OnSubmit="HandleLogin" FormName="UserLoginForm">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="UserName">Username:</label>
            <InputText id="UserName" class="form-control" @bind-Value="Login.UserName" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Login.UserName)" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Password">Password:</label>
            <InputText id="Password" class="form-control" @bind-Value="Login.Password" Type="password" />
            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Login.Password)" />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </EditForm>
</div>

@code {
    private Login Login { get; set; } = new Login();

    private async Task HandleLogin()
    {
        string userDomains = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserDomains");
        bool isValidLogin = IsValidLogin("LDAP://mycorp.com", "mycorp", Login.UserName, Login.Password, out string retMessage);
        if (isValidLogin)
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/dashboard");
        }
        else
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
        }
    }

    private bool IsValidLogin(string LDAPPath, string domainName, string userName, string password, out string retMessage)
    {
        bool returnValue = false;
        retMessage = null;

        try
        {
            // encode user input before being used in LDAP query.
            string safeUserName = EscapeLdapSearchFilter(userName);
            var userClaims = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.Claims;
            bool isAuthenticated = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;
          

            string email = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.
            FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

            var de = new DirectoryEntry(LDAPPath, userName, password);

            using (var ds = new DirectorySearcher(de) { Filter = "samaccountname=" + safeUserName })
            {
                SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
                if (sr == null)
                {
                    retMessage = "Invalid Login.";
                }
                else
                {
                    string userID = UserInformation.GetByName($"{domainName}\\{userName}", email);

                    returnValue = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retMessage = $"Error during LDAP login: {ex.Message}";
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    private static string EscapeLdapSearchFilter(string searchFilter)
    {
        StringBuilder escape = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < searchFilter.Length; i++)
        {
            char current = searchFilter[i];
            switch (current)
            {
                case '\\':
                    escape.Append(@"\5c");
                    break;
                case '*':
                    escape.Append(@"\2a");
                    break;
                case '(':
                    escape.Append(@"\28");
                    break;
                case ')':
                    escape.Append(@"\29");
                    break;
                case '\u0000':
                    escape.Append(@"\00");
                    break;
                case '/':
                    escape.Append(@"\2f");
                    break;
                default:
                    escape.Append(current);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return escape.ToString();
    }
}

userClaims is empty, isAuthenticated is false, email is null in the below code from above file
var userClaims = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.Claims; 
            bool isAuthenticated = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;
          
            string email = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.
            FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

My Program.cs
It has some Auth configuration I tried, but it didn't work, so that's commented.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using RCBuisinessLogic.Authentication;
using RCBuisinessLogic.DataAccess;
using RCWebApp.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
// Register IConfiguration
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<BaseDAL>();

// Register AuthenticationConfiguration
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationConfiguration>();

// Register UserInformation
builder.Services.AddTransient<UserInformation>();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

// Add authentication services and configure the custom authentication scheme.
//builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
//{
//    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "LDAP";
//    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "LDAP";
//})
//.AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, LdapAuthenticationHandler>("LDAP", options => { });

// Add authorization services
//builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
//{
//    // You can configure authorization policies here if needed.
//    options.AddPolicy("Authenticated", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());
//});

var app = builder.Build();

// Use authentication and authorization before handling routing
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

//app.Use(async (context, next) =>
//{
//    var user = context.User;

//    // Only redirect authenticated users if they are NOT trying to access '/userlogin'
//    if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/userlogin"))
//    {
//        // Redirect authenticated users to the dashboard or another page
//        context.Response.Redirect("/dashboard");
//        return;
//    }

//    await next();  // Continue the request pipeline
//});

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();

Tried out this middleware suggested by chatgpt but, it didn't work.

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using RCBuisinessLogic.Authentication;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class LdapAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    private readonly UserInformation _userInformation;

    public LdapAuthenticationHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock,
        UserInformation userInformation)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        _userInformation = userInformation;
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var username = Context.Request.Form["username"];
        var password = Context.Request.Form["password"];
        string domain = "mycorp.com";  // Adjust to your LDAP domain

        // Perform LDAP authentication here.
        var isAuthenticated = AuthenticateWithLdap(username, password, domain, out var userId);
        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            // Create claims and set the principal
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userId)  // Adjust according to your LDAP setup
            };

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "LDAP");
            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsPrincipal, "LDAP");
            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }

        return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid username or password.");
    }

    private bool AuthenticateWithLdap(string username, string password, string domain, out string userId)
    {
        userId = null;

        try
        {
            var ldapPath = $"LDAP://{domain}";
            using var de = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, username, password);
            using var ds = new DirectorySearcher(de)
            {
                Filter = $"(sAMAccountName={username})"
            };

            var result = ds.FindOne();
            if (result != null)
            {
                userId = result.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString(); // Or other user identifier
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Log error or handle it
        }

        return false;
    }
}


It is super shocking to see nobody worked on Blazor(.NET 8)/LDAP(Active Directory) integration.

The recommendation from GPT does not work because you need to add the given middleware in your program.cs. The below code will use cookies in your login and logout path to save user credential and then you willl have to use the code from GPT to manually populate the user claims and sign in the user using signInAsync
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Cookies")
.AddCookie("Cookies", options => {
                      options.LoginPath` = "/userlogin";
                      options.LogoutPath = "/logout";`
         });

Once that is done you will be able to access users in the httpcontext accessor
